# Binary XML Line#0 inflate exception?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable

I am getting this error everytime i try to run my app and i dont know why im trying to make a basic welcome screen for my app that will then transition to my homepage but at the moment the welcome screen does not load and the app just says "Unable to run app" when i run the project. I have tried Doing a clean build and Rebuild on the project and other fixes for this error that other people have had but still no luck.

Below i have posted the error the logcat is giving at run time.

```
Error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.ross.moviepickerapp, PID: 21507
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ross.moviepickerapp/com.example.ross.moviepickerapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                     at com.example.ross.moviepickerapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                     at com.example.ross.moviepickerapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                     at com.example.ross.moviepickerapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ross.moviepickerapp:drawable/welcomebackground" (7f060064) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060064 a=-1 r=0x7f060064}
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4245)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4152)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4002)
                                                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4249)
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:591)
                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:249)
                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:245)
                                                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:241)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:706) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                     at com.example.ross.moviepickerapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is my code for MainActivity:

```
package com.example.ross.moviepickerapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);
}
}
```

And here is my code for my XMl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ross.moviepickerapp.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/welcomebackground">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_to"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/movie_picker"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="italic|bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Could you also post the `welcomebackground` file? because your error says `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ross.moviepickerapp:drawable/welcomebackground" is not a Drawable (color or path)`

Comment: what is **`@drawable/welcomebackground`**

Comment: check that `drawable/welcomebackground` is drawable or not?

Comment: Sorry that fixed it it was a .jpg image that was in my drawable v24 folder but i changed it to a .png and put it in my drawable folder which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem with the line

```
android:background="@drawable/welcomebackground"
```

in the xml file. Try to comment this line and clean the project and run.

> Create a new android activity using new > empty activity and see how is work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.ross.moviepickerapp:drawable/welcomebackground" (7f060064) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060064 a=-1 r=0x7f060064}
```

you need to check this file.

you can add resouces via Android Studio , go to app>res>drawable>"Right Click">New>"Image Asset" or "Vector Asset"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is related to the android library version with compiledSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. Previously I got the error when I used :

1. compileSdkVersion 26
2. targetSdkVersion 26
3. 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
4. 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

then I changed to the newer version and it worked :

1. compileSdkVersion 27
2. targetSdkVersion 27
3. 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
4. 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

I hope this will help